# Java XPath and SimpleNamespaceContext for unknown prefix case

Tags: java, xml, xpath, namespaces

My Java program will accept an XPath expression from subscribers who want to select a specific set of CAP alerts, all of which are XML files valid against CAP schema version 1.1 or 1.2. My program will run the composed XPath expression as an XPath evaluate. However, the subscriber does not know what namespace prefixes are used in all of the CAP alerts, and some use no prefix.

We could insist that subscribers compose the XPath expression using the rather messy 'local-name' approach. For example, here is the expression to select on the "language" element equal to "en":

/*[local-name()='alert']/*[local-name()='info']/*[local-name()='language'][.= 'en']

BTW, to strictly prevent name conflicts, that mess ought to be prepended with another expression that selects only elements matching the CAP namespaceuri's:

//*[namespace-uri()='urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.1'] or //*[namespace-uri()='urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.2']

What I need is the simplest syntax that alert subscribers can use to provide the XPath filter expression to my program, even though the prefix is unknown.

I am intrigued by the SimpleNamespaceContext suggested by tomaj, but I cannot figure out whether it applies in this case nor how to implement it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: If you know the namespace  you do not need to know the namespace prefix  used in xml.  Register the namespace   with  a unique prefix (lets say `xx`) and use that in your xpath (`xx:alert/xx:info/xx:language[. ='en']` ).

Comment: I think you understand exactly what I would like to do. My question is: how do I: "Register the namespace with a unique prefix"  in Java using XPath?

Comment: Hm you question was about unknown (changing) prefixes. But now it seems you do not know how to use namespaces or even xapth in java at all? Please show what you tried up to now. And what the problem is.

Comment: I have tried dozens of approaches over the years. My latest attempted solution  was this:

import net.sf.practicalxml.xpath.NamespaceResolver;
NamespaceResolver nsResolver = new NamespaceResolver();
xPath.setNamespaceContext(nsResolver.addNamespace("cap", "urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.1"));
xPath.setNamespaceContext(nsResolver.addNamespace("cap", "urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.2"));

xPath.evaluate("/cap:alert/cap:info/cap:language[. ='en']");

Comment: You try to register different namespace ( `..:cap:1.1` and  `..:cap:1.2` to the same prefix `cap`. This will never work. So not your preefix is unknon but the used namespace? Is this namespace used for the whole file, or does it changes form element to element? If it ist for the wohle file (I assume)  you can try to read the used namespace in a first step.

Comment: The solution from Kim Homann is exactly what I need. Switching over to XPath 2.0 was pivotal.  
Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have XPath 2.0 or higher, then you can use the following syntax:

```
/*:alert/*:info/*:language[.= 'en']
```

Comment: Kim,  
Your approach is perfect, except I cannot risk an accidental match on a prefix of an element that was deliberately NOT from one or the other cap schema.  
Could you first restrict the selected elements to only those associated with namespace-uri()='urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.1' or namespace-uri()='urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.2' ?

Comment: In that case, I cannot think of anything better than the full notation: `/*[local-name()='alert'][namespace-uri()='urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.1' or namespace-uri()='urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.2']`

Comment: Actually, your solution is exactly what I need. I will instruct users to provide their XPath criteria using the simple syntax, e.g,  
`/*:info/*:language[.= 'en']`   

My Java code will then construct the full XPath 2.0 expression by prepending that criteria with the CAP namespaceuri restriction: 
`/*[local-name()='alert'][namespace-uri()='urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.1' or namespace-uri()='urn:oasis:names:tc:emergency:cap:1.2']`  

Thanks!